# 301 Redirect Error in 2nd part of URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having two issues (which I'm sure are related) with some 301 redirects we have setup via .htaccess in WordPress.

**Issue 1**

We have a site whose old URLs were:

url.com/about-us/cloud-computing/
url.com/about-us/shared-services/

We have now consolidated these two pages into one page whose url is:

url.com/about/

The issue is that when you go to one of the old URLs it redirects the first part of the string, but then appends the second part to it, though it doesn't exist anymore. e.g.

url.com/about-us/cloud-computing/ RETURNS url.com/about/cloud-computing/

so about-us has changed to about (which is correct) but it is still appending the second part of the string.

**Issue 2**

Where URLs have changed completely and have more than one string to them, it only changes the same string. E.g:

url.com/products/summary/ has been replaced with
url.com/solutions/features/

If you try and go to the old URL, the first part of the string changes, but the second doesn't RETURNING url.com/solutions/summary/.

**NB**

Pages where there was only one part to the string, now redirecting to a new page with only one part to its string, work fine.

Has anyone experienced this issue of only part of the URL being changed before, or can they advise on what might be going on?

All help much appreciated in advance, **below is an example of the some of the URLs from the .htaccess file.** For client confidentiality we have remove all references to the company name and any products.

Regards
J

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /about-us/ http://www.newurl.com/about/
Redirect 301 /about-us/about-product-company/ http://www.newurl.com/about/
Redirect 301 /about-us/about-us/ http://www.newurl.com/about/
Redirect 301 /about-us/cloud-computing-software-as-a-service-shared-services-company/ http://www.newurl.com/services/software-as-a-service-saas/
Redirect 301 /about-us/one-application-multiple-products/ http://www.newurl.com/legacy-pages/one-application-multiple-products/
Redirect 301 /about-us/testimonials/ http://www.newurl.com/about/
Redirect 301 /free-whitepaper-downloads/ http://www.newurl.com/download-registration/
Redirect 301 /products/product-time-recording-company/ http://www.newurl.com/solutions/time-recording/
Redirect 301 /products/product-time-recording-company/product-time-recording-detailed-summary-company/ http://www.newurl.com/solutions/time-recording/
Redirect 301 /products/product-time-recording-company/product-time-recording-video-overview-company/ http://www.newurl.com/solutions/time-recording/
Redirect 301 /html-sitemap/ http://www.newurl.com/sitemap/
```

Comment: Hi jameszest, you'll need to provide the htaccess you're working with to get any real help. From your question it looks like your rules are set up wrong, but we'll need to actually see them to help you.

Comment: Post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Hi guys, example of .htaccess file provided as requested